# Solving for $a = b * c$ when $b$ is an unknown

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose I have the equation $a = b * c$, and I have the values for $a$ and $c$. How would I determine the value of $b$?

Example: $\quad20 = b * 2.$

Comment: Divide both sides by $c$, assuming $c\ne 0$.

Comment: Thanks....I'm very rusty on my algebra, clearly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $c \neq 0$ then you can divide the equation by $c$ and you can find $b$. If $c=0$ then $a=0$, so $b$ can be everything except infinity.

Another way is to look at all divisors of $a$, and select divisors which contains $c$ and try to find $b$. This works if $a$ is not a big number.

Comment: The second part is irrelevant. $a$ and $c$ are assumed to be known. We need not look at divisors, we just divide the numbers.